# How do I create a category filter like this in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I create a dropdown for categories on the right sidebar in wordpress. I looked at some tutorials but all of them shows how to create a menu with dropdown that goes in the header.

I want the category filter to be like this specifically in the sidebar. Does this require extra plugin or can be done in the wordpress itself?

Any help would be appreciated. The wordpress theme is Hueman.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In case anyone else wants to know. Here's how:

1. Install the classic widgets plugin
2. Drag the categories to your widget area